AWS Elastic Cache Redis - Auth token rotated
I have created in AWS an Elastic Cache with the Redis engine, family 7 via Terraform.
This Redis was created five months ago. Today the only one app which is using this redis is getting wrong password message in its logs. I saw in redis and any logs and other stuff no indication about password (AUTH token) rotation.
Global parameters doesn't see any info about token rotation.
Its any group parameters or AWS sometimes change AUTH token (such as SEC update?)
Thanks for any help
Any help about automatic rotation AUTH tokens

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
